# OneDrive sync client installation taking forever

Tags: installation, sync, process, onedrive, resource-usage

Went to [How to install the OneDrive for Business (formerly SkyDrive Pro) sync client for SharePoint 2013 and SharePoint Online](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2903984).

Ran the installer, but it's more than 1 hour since it's running and I have 1240 ***officec2rclient.exe*** processes.

[image: officec2rclient.exe]

Is this the normal installation behavior?

Answer (score 0):

This is not normal behavior. While installation can take some time, one hour is far too long. I would try killing the process and reinstalling per [these instructions](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2903984/en-us).

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. But the link you provided is exactly the link that I included in my post. Besides that, there's a notification pop-up saying not to go offline or restart... So what guarantees that reinstalling won't hang again?